# Run a bash script with php from Centos 7

Tags: php, bash, wget

I want to execute a shell script from a web page in PHP.

my shell script (test.sh with chmod +x right):

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -la
wget www.google.fr
```

my php page (index.php) :

```
<?php
echo system('./test.sh');
echo exec('./test.sh');
echo shell_exec('./test.sh');
?>
```

In this situation I can run the script but the wget return nothing but the `ls` command work. If I run the script directly in command line (php index.php) everything is ok. What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean, `return nothing`? Are there any files generated in the folder, and if not, does the web-user have write permissions there?

Comment: I mean the wget command do nothing. No file are generated. And everything is in 755 permission.

Comment: maybe PHP is not running in a safe_mode?

Comment: safe_mode is off

Comment: perhaps enable in php.ini  display_error, error_reporting see if you can see anything !

Comment: oh also make sure that the owner of the file is your Apache user